# Joint probability: Does $P(x) = P(x,y) + P(x,\bar{y})$ hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given two random variables $x$ and $y$ and equation: $P(x) = P(x,y) + P(x,\bar{y})$

**Assuming $x$ and $y$ independent, this will hold:**

$$P(x) = P(x,y) + P(x,\bar{y})$$

$$P(x) = P(x)P(y) + P(x)P(\bar{y})$$

$$P(x) = P(x)(P(y)+P(\bar{y}))$$

$$P(x) = P(x)(1)$$

$$P(x) = P(x)$$

**Assuming $x$ and $y$ are dependent, will this same property hold?** This is not immediately clear to me.

Comment: If $y$ is a *random variable*, what does $\bar y$ mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be very similar to your proof above, but using conditional probabilities:

$$
\begin{align*}
P(X,Y) + P(X, \overline Y) &= P(X) P(Y\mid X)+P(X)P(\overline Y\mid X)\\
&= P(X)\left[P(Y\mid X) + P(\overline Y\mid X)\right]\\
&= \cdots
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: I am not sure if this argument holds if $P(X) = 0$, and invoking conditional probabilities here is I think a bit off: it would be like saying "1 + 1 = 2 because $\int_{(0,1\]} dx + \int_{(1,2\]} dx = \int_{(0,2\]} dx $ and integration is linear"

Comment: I had a similar concern.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it will; this is actually an immediate consequence of an "axiom" of probability, namely, two disjoint events have their probabilities add.

Probability is about measuring sizes of sets, and an axiom of probability (or rather how you define a probability measure) is that two disjoint sets have their sizes add up, so if there are 5 apples in bag A and 7 apples in bag B, and A and B are "disjoint" bags, there are 12 apples in bag A and B, and this will be true whether B always had 2 extra apples than A (i.e. even if they were dependent).

Mathematically, you can simply write $P(X) = P(X \cap Y) + P(X \cap \bar{Y})$ where $X$ and $Y$ are sets, since $X \cap Y$ and $X \cap \bar{Y}$ are definitely disjoint! (You can prove it, it should be a fun exercise). No need to prove.